# ReGex to match exact word, ignoring words containing it as a substring?

Tags: regex

I'd like to match all instances of `prod` in a large file. The file contains arrangements such as:

- `prod`
- `"prod"`
- `.prod`
- `prod.`
- `prod*`
- `(prod`
- `production`

I'd like way to match (and ultimately, replace) all instances of the above, *except for the last result*.  The best I've come up with so far is just a simple `\W`: https://regex101.com/r/8bOrcS/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with alternations to match a word boundary or one of the given non-word characters around `prod`:

```
(?:[".(_*-]|\b)prod(?:[".)_*-]|\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c1NX6R/1)

`(?:[".(_*-]|\b)` matches a word boundary or one of the given special characters.